# Groovy - how to Decode a base 64 string and save it to a pdf/doc in local directory

Tags: groovy, soapui

**Question**

I need help with decoding a base 64 string and saving it to a pdf/doc in local directory using groovy
This script should work in SOAP UI 
The base64 string is 52854 characters long

**I have tried the following**

```
File f = new File("c:\\document1.doc")
FileOutputStream out = null 
byte[] b1 = Base64.decodeBase64(base64doccontent);
out = new FileOutputStream(f)
try {
    out.write(b1)
} finally {
    out.close()
}
```

**But - it gives me below error**

No signature of method: static org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [base64stringlong] Possible solutions: decodeBase64([B), encodeBase64([B), encodeBase64([B, boolean)

Comment: if `base64doccontent` is a String, try: `base64doccontent.decodeBase64()`. http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the base64 encoded text is coming from a file, a minimal example for soapUI would be:

```
import com.itextpdf.text.*
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

String encodedContents = new File('/path/to/file/base64Encoded.txt')
    .getText('UTF-8')
byte[] b1 = encodedContents.decodeBase64();

// Save as a text file
new File('/path/to/file/base64Decoded.txt').withOutputStream {
        it.write b1
} 

// Or, save as a PDF
def document = new Document()
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, 
    new FileOutputStream('/path/to/file/base64Decoded.pdf'))

document.open()
document.add(new Paragraph(new String(b1)))
document.close()
```

The `File.withOutputStream` method will ensure the stream is closed when the closure returns.

Or, to convert the byte array to a PDF, I used [iText](https://developers.itextpdf.com/downloads). I dropped `itextpdf-5.5.13.jar` in soapUI's `bin/ext` directory and restarted and then it was available for Groovy.

Comment: Thanks so much @craigcaulfield 

Sorry about a late reply. I tried your method using the itextpdf-5.5.13.jar , but I am getting below error when trying to run this 
    `No signature of method: java.lang.String.getText() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [UTF-8] Possible solutions: getAt(java.lang.String), getAt(java.util.Collection), getAt(groovy.lang.IntRange), getAt(int), getAt(groovy.lang.Range), getAt(groovy.lang.EmptyRange)`

Do I need to import any other library ?

Comment: This is the code I am using for saving to pdf from a base64 string as per your previous suggestion 
    
 `def encodedContent = actualbase64.getText('UTF-8') //actualbase64 is the base 64 encoded string 
    byte[] b1 = encodedContents.decodeBase64() 
    def document = new Document() PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream('D:/path/to/file/base64Decoded.pdf')) 
    document.open() 
    document.add(new Paragraph(new String(b1))) 
    document.close()`

Comment: The above example assumes you're reading the encoded content from a file into a String. But, your `actualbase64` is already a String, so you don't need the line `def encodedContent = actualbase64.getText('UTF-8')`. Just use `byte[] b1 = actualbase64.decodeBase64()`.

Comment: That works - thanks again @craigcaulfield. But now the pdf content is gibberish  like below , how can I show it to be fully formatted text. If I manually convert it using a converter , that works   `%PDF-1.5
5 0 obj
<</Type /Page/Parent 3 0 R/Contents 6 0 R/MediaBox [0 0 595.29998779
841.90002441]/Resources<</Font<</FAAAAI 8 0 R/FAAABF 15 0.`

Comment: This method has worked for me with the simple text files I usually encounter in soapUI, but richer content may need more massaging. Because there's not much room in these comments, it might be best to resolve this question and raise a separate question with an example of the documents you're working with.

Comment: Thanks for all your help and pointers  - I now have a work around, I have directly added the base64encoded output to an HTML file like below using groovy and it now directly can be opened by chrome to view the PDF `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Show PDF</h1><embed width=1000 height=3000 src="data:application/pdf;base64,actualbase64content,"type="application/pdf"></body></html>`