# Decoding a base64 string from JSON content in SOAPUI using groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I get a json response from a REST api that looks like below

```
{
  "parentnode1":    {
  "childnode1": "abc12345-123-1234-1234-64a0251575f9",
  "childnode2": "VAL1",
  "childnode3": "format/pdf",
  "childnode4": "name.pdf",
  "base64content": "JVBERi0xLjUNCiW1tbW1DQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9UeXBlL0NhdGFsb2cvUGFnZXMgMiAwRU9G"},
  "messages": "This is a message"
}
```

I want to decode  the value of `"base64content"` and then convert that into a pdf file and save it to a local directory. Is this possible in SOAP UI and Groovy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this groovy script but have not tested it in SOAPUI (have never used it). Try this and let me know what happens:

```
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def object = jsonSlurper.parseText (json_response)

String content_decoded = object.base64content.decodeBase64()

def file = new java.io.File("output.pdf")     
FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(file)     
fos.write( content_decoded )     
fos.flush()     
fos.close()
```

Comment: Thanks @letimome , if I used the above solution with code per below 

`String content_decoded = actualbase64.decodeBase64()
def file = new java.io.File('D:/Apps/Intellidoc_LVL/base64Decoded2.pdf')  
log.info file
log.info content_decoded   
FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(file)     
fos.write(content_decode)     
fos.flush()     
fos.close()`

Comment: But I am getting below error

`startup failed: Script104.groovy: 73: Invalid variable name. Must start with a letter but was:   . At [73:73] @ line 73, column 73. lidoc_LVL/base64Decoded2.pdf')  ^` , do you know why its unable to interpret the file path

Comment: The solution here worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49593847/groovy-how-to-decode-a-base-64-string-and-save-it-to-a-pdf-doc-in-local-direct/49598874?noredirect=1#comment87387624_49598874

Comment: Then this question is duplicated. since the issue was solved for the original question, I recommend you delete this question.